# Why does Swift require both argument label and parameter name in function declaration?

Tags: swift

Why does Swift require both argument label and parameter name in a function declaration? I'm learning Swift and thus far haven't seen a use for an argument label.

Comment: Better readability when calling the method (parameter names are not visible there).

Comment: Swift doesn't require that you specify an argument label in the function declaration, by default it will be the same as the parameter name. I would highly recommend you read the [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) section of the language guide.

Comment: See [API Design Guidelines: Argument Labels](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#argument-labels) or [WWDC 2016 Swift API Design Guidelines video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/403/) for examples/rationale where the argument label and parameter name may differ. But as Hamish points out, when they're the same, you can omit the argument label and it will default to the parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

The argument label is chosen from the point of view of the caller. The parameter name is chosen from the point of view of the implementer. Sometimes the same name is a good choice from both points of view, sometimes it isn't. Swift gives you the freedom to make good choices from both points of view.

Comment: If you use only one value for the argument label and parameter name what is it called?

Answer (score 1):

By default ,parameters use their parameter name as their argument label.
-The Swift Programming Language 4.0.3